# How can I change the destination of Azure AD group writeback after on-premise groups have been created?

Tags: entra-id, azureadconnect

I tried running this command to change the destination, but it didn't seem to work. I thought that it might move the existing groups to the new location after the next sync.

```
$a = Get-ADSyncGlobalSettings
($a.parameters | where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.GroupWriteBack.Container"}).Value = "[new destination]"
$a | Set-ADSyncGlobalSettings
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the destination, I had to:

- Use the Azure AD GUI to disable Group Writeback
- Allow a sync to happen (existing groups are deleted)
- Re-enable Group Writeback and update the destination
- Allow a sync to happen (groups are recreated in the new location)